# How to require vendor script with Browserify?

Tags: javascript, browserify

I am new to Browserify and I made it work with my own modules (nicely works with gulp). However, now I am trying to include external vendor script (prism syntax highlighter).

This is my bundle.js:

```
'use strict';

var $ = require('jquery'),
    animate404 = require('./modules/404'),
    prism = require('./vendor/prism');

$(function() {
    new prism();
    new animate404(document.querySelector('.title404'));
});
```

So, then 404 module works nicely, however minified prism highlighter does not. Console shows error on *new prism();*:

```
Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function
```

Am I doing something wrong? I tried googling, but could not find the answer... Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because prism is not CommonJS compatible, you have to use [`browserify-shim`](https://github.com/thlorenz/browserify-shim).

First `npm install browserify-shim --save-dev`. Then in your `package.json` file

```
{
  "browser": {
    "prism": "./vendor/prism/prism.js"
  },
  "browserify-shim": {
    "prism": "Prism"
  }
}
```

And then in your bundle.js file

`var prism = require('prism')`